# Chromedriver --screenshot not working in headless mode?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I'm using new chrome driver headless mode (Chrome v59, mac os) with webdriver. but unfortunately, screenshot option given in headless mode is not working for me. following code shows the chrome options configured.

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-gpu");
chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1980x960");
chromeOptions.addArguments("screenshot");
```

I'm getting unknown chrome error:

```
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477690 (c53f4ad87510ee97b5c3425a14c0e79780cdf262),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.05 seconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ip-192-168-13-242.ec2.internal', ip: '192.168.13.242', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at com.axonix.utilities.SeleniumDriverWrapper.setupNewDriverInstance(SeleniumDriverWrapper.java:78)
        at com.axonix.utilities.SeleniumDriverWrapper.<init>(SeleniumDriverWrapper.java:55)
        at com.axonix.utilities.SeleniumInterface.<init>(SeleniumInterface.java:30)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
        at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
        at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
        at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:300)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.run(CucumberFeature.java:165)
        at cucumber.runtimee.run(Runtime.java:122)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)
        at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

Comment: What does not working mean? Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you.

Comment: @JeffC updated my question with error i'm getting!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`window-size`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc?q=kWindowSize&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=84) argument expects string format `800,600`, try this instead:

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1980,960");
```

Also, you have a typo in your [`screenshot`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/headless/app/headless_shell_switches.cc?q=kScreenshot&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=59) argument:

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("screenshot");
```

---

Here's a great reference of all available Chromium command line switches:

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/